# A problem about degrees of minimal polynomials for two arbitrary elements in an extension field

Tags: field-theory

I'm struggling to come up with a reasonable proof for the following problem:

Suppose $E$ is an extension field of a field $K$ and that $a$ and $b$ are algebraic elements in $E$.  Show that the degree of the minimal polynomial for $b$ in $K$($a$)[x] is less than or equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial for $b$ in $K$[x].

I've thought about this problem for a few hours now to no avail, I think I'm just overthinking and overlooking something due to time pressure. Here's what I'm wondering, should I use the multipilcativity formula for degrees or is it something simpler?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: $K[x]\subset K(a)[x]$.

Comment: Should I be thinking about the linear factor (x - $a$)?

Comment: Huh? Linear factor of what?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the ring $K[x]$ is the set of all polynomials in $x$ with coefficients contained in $K$, and therefore the ring $K(a)[x]$ is the set of all polynomials in $x$ with coefficients contained in $K(a)$. Now, $K(a)$ is by definition the smallest field containing $a$ and $K$, so it at least contains $K$. So a polynomial with coefficients in $K$ is obviously a polynomial with coefficients in $K(a)$.

That is why, the ring $K(a)[x]$ contains the ring $K[x]$, and the point is that the minimal polynomial for $b$ in $K[x]$ will therefore be in $K(a)[x]$ as well, although it may or may not split further, in which case it will be smaller.Hence it follows that the minimal polynomial for $b$ in $K(a)[x]$ has degree less than or equal to the degree of the minimal polynomial of $b$ in $K[x]$.